# What does ‘to immolate (someone) to one’s manes’ mean?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, idiom-meaning

What does the phrase ***to immolate someone to one’s manes*** mean as it used in the following pair of literary citations?

- *“Do thou, brave wolf, avenge our queen, by **immolating this traitor to her august manes**.”*
  ― translation of [Jean de La Fontaine’s *Fables*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fables_de_La_Fontaine), *Les obsèques de la Lionne* (‘The Obsequies of the Lioness’) [via Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ggpmAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=%22Do+thou,+brave+wolf,+avenge+our+queen,+by+immolating%22&source=bl&ots=sJChq7sWmN&sig=ACfU3U2EC5wJkEa3ZevHbkcDy9Pw3oFVAQ&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22Do%20thou%2C%20brave%20wolf%2C%20avenge%20our%20queen%2C%20by%20immolating%22&f=false).
- *“* [...] *whence he received the order **to immolate his mother to the paternal manes**.”*
  ― [*Le Antichità di Ercolano Esposte*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Antichit%C3%A0_di_Ercolano_Esposte), [via Google Books](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N6dAQgs3SFsC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=whence+he+received+the+order+to+immolate+his+mother+to+the+paternal+manes.%22&source=bl&ots=-a4c7Rfhv1&sig=ACfU3U2Mw5KaGvSf804E07zFUzEeWSm2aA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEu8_0t_7oAhXjQhUIHZmkAHgQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=whence%20he%20received%20the%20order%20to%20immolate%20his%20mother%20to%20the%20paternal%20manes.%22&f=false).

After long ratiocinations upon *to immolate* (*someone*) *to one’s manes*, I settled upon the following meaning: “to seek revenge upon someone”.  I would nevertheless like certain further explanation both of grammar and of meaning regarding how this idiomatic phrase has been used in the two citations provided above.

My specific questions are:

1. What does *august* refer to? To the way the retaliation should be committed?
2. Is *the manes* the character of the person who should be avenged?
3. What does *paternal* refer to? To the person who should be revenged?

Comment: Please add links and attributions. We could be wasting our time if these are merely some modern historical novelist's attempts to sound period. // 'Immolating someone to their august manes' brings to mind a more modern (fixed) phrase, 'grabbing someone by the short and curlies'. And 'paternal manes', 'She's got her father's hair'.

Comment: First sentence: 
Jean de La Fontaine : "The obsequies of the lioness"
Second one:
[here](https://books.google.fr/books?id=N6dAQgs3SFsC&pg=PA62&lpg=PA62&dq=whence+he+received+the+order+to+immolate+his+mother+to+the+paternal+manes.%22&source=bl&ots=-a4c7Rfhv1&sig=ACfU3U2Mw5KaGvSf804E07zFUzEeWSm2aA&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjEu8_0t_7oAhXjQhUIHZmkAHgQ6AEwAXoECAsQAQ#v=onepage&q=whence%20he%20received%20the%20order%20to%20immolate%20his%20mother%20to%20the%20paternal%20manes.%22&f=false) 'Le Antichità di Ercolano' Esposte

Comment: And did you look up the meaning of _immolate?_

Comment: Immolate means to offer as a sacrifice, does it not ?

Comment: It is/was used the same way as 'sacrifice', "immolated them to their gods".

Comment: So, to someone's manes here refers to the deceased person ? One just uses manes as a metaphor ?

Comment: Well, La Fontaine was writing about a mythical world of talking animals, and the other reference is to classical antiquity - not Rome, admittedly, but maybe the ancient Greeks had a similar belief. If anyone were to use the expression today, it would be as  a metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

*Manes* (Latin) - (in ancient Roman belief) the souls of dead ancestors, worshipped as benevolent spirits.  (Definition from Oxford Dictionaries).

*August* = highly respected (presumably referring to the queen's spirit).

*Paternal* - presumably the spirit of the subject's father.

Comment: Ah, general reference. And educated guesswork.

Answer (score 0):

The verb [immolate](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/immolate)

> To kill as a sacrifice especially by fire

The term "august manes" in La Fontaine may have the double meaning of "great ancestor" but also "great hair" like a lion's mane.
However I would be surprised if that particular wordplay exists in the original French.

Comment: Suggested improvements: “However❟ I **would** be surprised if that particular [*jeu de mots*](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/273111) **exist*ed*** in the original French.”

Comment: In French, a lion's hair is called a *crinière*, so if it was a pun, it would have to have been a bilingual pun. I wouldn't rule this out, though.